# Chrome extension passing data from background.js to new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I want to show a page with some of the usager's usage statistics. I have been trying to go about this by creating a new tab from the background.js to display an HTML page:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: '/results.html',
    active: true
});
```

where `results.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <script src='js/charts.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='myChart' style='height:400px; max-width:800px; background-color:red;'></canvas>
  </body>
  <script src='js/results.js'></script>
</html>
```

The problem is that I then need to pass the actual usage data from the background.js page to this new results.html page. The only thing I can think of is to add another content script that attaches to the results.html page.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.results.html"
        ],
        "js": ["js/results_content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
]
```

This doesn't seem to work, otherwise, I could then have the background page send the data through the `results_content.js` script and display the charts.

The only other idea I can think of is to just open a new tab to obscurewebsite.com and have a content script that does something like `document.body.innerHTML = ""` and rebuild my page using only javascript. I don't love this solution.

Is there a way to pass information through the `chrome.tabs` reference? Or another way to pass the data? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And it does when I'm using regular web pages with contentScripts. But in this case, the problem is that I am creating a new tab, which has address `chrome-extension://bpbigdfdiiiafmmfeghpaikloanahaan/results.html` and I am not able to attach a contentScript.

Comment: See [Modify a tab with an extension html file inside when opened from popup](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: Perfect. `chrome.storage.local` seems to be the perfect trick!